# Should I delete or set a variable to "deleted" in django/postgresql?

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql

Specifically for my app, I have created this model in order to allow a user (the user_parent) to follow other users.

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user_parent = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name="follow_set")
    users_followed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="follow_followed")
```

Whenever a user parent follows another user, the user being followed is added to the variable users_followed.

Right now I am trying to figure out how best to unfollow other users. Do I delete the user being followed from the users_followed variable or should I add another field to the model describing whether the user is still being followed or not?

Which is the most expensive action for the database to perform?

Comment: It would be the same in terms of expense. Since it is a table update. So either approach should be fine

Comment: @karthikr if that is true then I'd be happy to accept your comment as an answer if you repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be the same in terms of expense, since it is a table update. So either approach should be fine